# Redirection over popup pages and show progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharepoint

I need to open a modal popup page from a buttons click, and on that page based on some user input and post some computation logics I need to redirect to other pages. This is in context to Share Point custom solution development, over a visual web part.

Everything is working fine locally. But, once deployed to staging environment the response of the server is too slow. So, I need a way to notify the user about the Work In Progress, during redirection from one page to another page over modal popup. I can't use AJAX tool kit or update panel.

Can you suggest me a good approach to achieve the same.

Comment: Show your code what are using to load the page.

Comment: On Button's click we need to redirect from one popup page to another, over the same modal dialog. Just like - Response.Redirect("~/.../../abc.aspx");

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has functionality built in to notify users of long running processes. You can use the `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose`. Such as

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Loading", "Please Wait", 76, 330);
```

More information is available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408140(v=office.14).aspx. The parameters are: `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(title, message, height, width);`

Also, in case you're not aware, the [SP.UI.ModalDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410259(v=office.14).aspx) class has some additional useful methods such as ShowPopupDialog and showModalDialog.